# iOS Push Notifications using NodeJS

Tags: ios, node.js, apple-push-notifications

I have a requirement to implement the server side code for pushing notifications to an iOS app. I have followed the link below.

https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/developing-ios-push-notifications-nodejs

The problem is I always get 'Insufficient credentials' message. I've also tried with another node.js module by name 'apn' but with no help.

Has anyone tried either of these modules successfully? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Most likely your APS certificate is invalid. Have you included the private key into certificate bundle?

Comment: Used `apn` node module. Below is the response I get when sending push notifications `apn Initialising connection +0ms
  apn Initialising module +0ms
  apn 1 left to send +0ms
  apn Connection established +1s
  apn Transmitting notification from buffer +1ms
  apn Socket drained +0ms 0
���軵��~�ҏ�n��^{.�
                �b�q9
���軵��~�ҏ�n��^nsmitted to:{.�
                �b�q9
  apn 0 left to send +1ms
  apn Socket closed +1ms 0`. Though the response says message was transmitted but I see nothing on device. I have cross checked the device token.

Comment: Do you receive any errors on device when subscribing to remote notifications? And what kind of payload you pass to device? Are you sure app is not running in foreground while sending notification?